# what does it mean when I see a function on a delegate with the following parameters id<Type>?

Tags: objective-c

Hello I have a possible basic question. On objective C, I have seen the following format when creating a delegate:

Code:

```
@protocol someDelegate<NSObject>
@optional
-(void)someFunc(id<Type>)item;
@end
```

Does this mean when I am using the delegate function I can send an object of that type only? if so, why can I just do as for example param: NSString. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Type` in your function signature is a protocol and not a class type (like the `NSString` in your question).

The type `id<someProtocol>` means any object type which implements `someProtocol`. For example, `NSSavePanel` has a property `delegate`:

```
@property(assign) id<NSOpenSavePanelDelegate> delegate;
```

The type states that *any* object is acceptable as long as it implements the `NSOpenSavePanelDelegate` protocol.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can send any type of object using the delegate function like :

```
@protocol someDelegate<NSObject>
@optional
- (void)someFunc:(NSString *)item;
```

If you are asking for delegate, then below is the explanation :

```
@property (assign) id<someDelegate> delegate;
```

Objective-C uses angle brackets to indicate conformance to a protocol.This object could be of any class, so the basic property type will be id. The only thing that is known about the object is that it conforms to the relevant protocol.